# Why does getUrl fail when using transforms on a translatable asset?

Tags: assets, localization, image-transforms

I have a project with the following code:

```
{% if entry.filmPoster | length %}
    <img src="{{ entry.filmPoster.first().getUrl('filmPoster') }}" alt="">
{% elseif entry.locale('en_gb').filmPoster | length %}{# fall back to English if there is one #}
    <img src="{{ entry.locale('en_gb').filmPoster.first().getUrl('filmPoster') }}" alt="">
{% endif %}
```

filmPoster is an Asset field, and it is translatable. It's set to restrict uploads to a single folder, and the upload location is [whats on] {slug}

In the back end, I go to an Entry and upload an asset in this field in English, save, switch to Welsh, upload the Welsh version of the asset and save. In both cases, in the CMS, I can switch between languages for the entry and see the correct image asset in each locale. If I then look on the server, I can see the correct files have been saved in the appropriate file-path:

```
/content/whats-on/entry-title/image-name.jpg
/content/whats-on/entry-title-in-welsh/image-name-welsh.jpg
```

On the front end template, however, the image for the Welsh version is a 404 broken image.

However, if I remove the transform from the equation, the correct image loads...

```
{% if entry.filmPoster | length %}
    <img src="{{ entry.filmPoster.first().getUrl() }}" alt="">
{% elseif entry.locale('en_gb').filmPoster | length %}{# fall back to English if there is one #}
    <img src="{{ entry.locale('en_gb').filmPoster.first().getUrl() }}" alt="">
{% endif %}
```

Why is attempting to use a transform breaking? What have I got wrong?

All I see in the logs is:

```
2016/10/13 09:39:03 [warning] [application] [Forced] Image “entry-title-in-welsh/image-name-welsh.jpg” cannot be found
```